# Nagios (OP5) Postfix, Client does not have permissions to send as this sender - but testmail work

Tags: postfix, exchange

I use the Nagios based OP5 monitoring system with postfix. If i send a testmail from OP5 Portal, the message will be received. But if a message is send cause a problem, i would get the error "Client does not have permissions to send as this sender"

Maillog by sending a testmail from OP5 Portal

```
Mar 16 11:41:36 op5-system postfix/pickup[16667]: E6D2D80D33: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 16 11:41:36 op5-system postfix/cleanup[470]: E6D2D80D33: message-id=<20150316104136.E6D2D80D33@op5-system.localdomain>
Mar 16 11:41:36 op5-system postfix/qmgr[1613]: E6D2D80D33: from=<root@op5-system.localdomain>, size=379, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 16 11:41:37 op5-system postfix/smtp[476]: E6D2D80D33: to=<root@op5-system>, relay=relayserver[192.168.1.2]:25, delay=0.78, delays=0.1/0.16/0.03/0.48, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20150316104136.E6D2D80D33@op5-system.localdomain> [InternalId=34904401] Queued mail for delivery)
Mar 16 11:41:37 op5-system postfix/qmgr[1613]: E6D2D80D33: removed
```

Mailog by sending a mail, cause a notification from op5-system

```
Mar 17 13:13:18 op5-system postfix/pickup[30229]: 04FDB80C87: uid=299 from=<monitor>
Mar 17 13:13:18 op5-system postfix/cleanup[31004]: 04FDB80C87: message-id=    <20150317121318.04FDB80C87@op5-system.localdomain>
Mar 17 13:13:18 op5-system postfix/qmgr[1610]: 04FDB80C87: from=<monitor@op5-system.localdomain>,  size=1082, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 17 13:13:18 op5-system postfix/smtp[31006]: 04FDB80C87: to=<root@op5-system>, relay=relayserver[192.168.1.2]:25, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0.01/0.02/0.01, dsn=5.7.1,  status=bounced (host relayserver[192.168.1.2] said: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have  permissions to send as this sender (in reply to end of DATA command))
Mar 17 13:13:18 op5-system postfix/bounce[31007]: 04FDB80C87: sender non-delivery notification: 15B3880C8F
Mar 17 13:13:18 op5-system postfix/qmgr[1610]: 04FDB80C87: removed
```

What can be a possible reason?

Thanks

Comment: Post the output of `grep 04FDB80C87 maillog` and `grep E6D2D80D33 maillog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message from exchange was pretty clear here

> 550 5.7.1 Client does not have  permissions to send as this sender

It means exchange only permitted your host to send email with sender **root@op5-system.localdomain**. Unfortunately notification email use **monitor@op5-system.localdomain** as sender address.

From OP5 Knowledge Base, there two options to solve your problem

- [Using postfix generic maps](https://kb.op5.com/display/HOWTOs/Sending+outgoing+email+messages+(notifications)+through+an+SMTP+relay+server). You need to tell postfix to rewrite the sender address from monitor@op5-system.localdomain to root@op5-system.localdomain.

  ```
  # Postfix main.cf
  smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

  #/etc/postfix/generic
  monitor@op5-system.localdomain root@op5-system.localdomain
  ```

  Don't forget to postmap the file
- [Set `--from` parameter in notification commands](https://kb.op5.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10944891#Howdoesnotificationswork?-Notificatione-mailsender). Append it with `--from root@op5-system.localdomain`. For example

  ```
  command_name=host-notify
  command_line=$USER3$/notify/poller_notify_send.pl --from root@op5-system.localdomain --other-argument
  ```

Comment: The first option, i have already done. But the second solve my problem. Thank you very much for your help!!